# почему подчеркивается красным *c*fact(*c - 1);

Tags: c, рекурсия

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int fact(int *c) {
if (*c <= 0) return 1;
else return *c*fact(*c - 1);
}
void main(void) {
int n;
scanf_s("%d", &n);
fact(&n);
printf("%d",n);
_getch();
}
```

почему в этой рекурсивной функции проблема с указателями ?
А если не пользоваться указателями , то  как тогда мне возвращать значение обратно в главную программу и пользоваться этим значением в главной программе?

Comment: при последующих вызовах fact(*c - 1) параметр *c-1 - это явно уже не указатель

Comment: Потому что `*c - 1` имеет тип `int` а не `int*`

Comment: @tilin и куда будет "указывать" `c-1`?

Comment: @andy.37уже никуда )

Comment: @andy.37, и что делать ?

Comment: А без указателей написать не хотите?

Comment: @Jenssen,а как тогда мне возвращать значение обратно в главную программу и пользоваться этим значение в главной программе ?

Answer (score 2):

при последующих вызовах fact(*c - 1) параметр *c-1 - это явно уже не указатель, а вполне себе значение. Указатели здесь вообще лишние, по моему

```
#include<stdio.h>

int fact(int c) {
 if (c == 1) return c;
 return c*fact(c - 1);
}

void main(void) {
 int n;
 scanf("%d", &n);
 printf("%d",fact(n));
}
```

Comment: Но я хочу использовать полученное значение из функции дальше

Comment: а, понял, просто так сделаю : r=fact(n)

Comment: @Elvin и что этому мешает?

Answer (score 2):

Если уж позарез нужно с указателями, то как-то так:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f(int* v)
{
    if (1 >= *v)
        return 1;
    int current = *v;
    --(*v);
    return current * f(v);
}

int g(int v)
{
    if (1 >= v) return 1;
    return v * g(v-1);
}

int main(void)
{
    int a = 5;
    printf("\n%d\n", f(&a));
    printf("%d\n", g(5));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если хотите использовать указатели, то можно так:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int fact(int* c) 
{
    if (*c == 0) // отрицательное значение не стоит использовать
        return 1;
    else 
    {
        int var = *c - 1;
        int* tmp = &var;
        // int* tmp = new int(*c - 1); // C++
        int result = (*c) * fact(tmp);
        // delete tmp; // C++
        return result;
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("%d", fact(&n));
}
```

Обратите внимание, в Вашем коде ошибка в возвращаемом значении при 0. Должно быть 1. Также факториал определен только на множестве натуральных числе с нулем. В случае получения значения `n < 0` лучше добавить соответствующие проверки с выдачей ошибки.

Comment: автор хочет на Си

Comment: @tilin а что не так?

Comment: а n<=0 пойдет ?

Comment: @Jenssen new/delete из с++

Comment: @Elvin брать факториал от отрицательного числа не здорово, а от 0 он равен 1.

Comment: @tilin ну я не пишу на C, и для меня new/delete из C, поскольку в крестах есть smart-pointers и make-функции, до-свиданья-пока указатели в С-стиле...

Comment: @tilin так правильно?